# UIPageViewController cancelled child UIView touches

Tags: touch, uipageviewcontroller

I have a UIPageViewController which holds several UIViewControllers. Each UIViewController's view has a subview: MyUIView. I override touchesBegan and all other 3 methods in MyUIView.

When I swipe from up to bottom in MyUIView, I got -touchesMoved:withEvent: called with no problem, but when I swipe from left to right, the UIPageViewController scrolls, and -touchesCancelled:withEvent: in MyUIView got called.

I didn't call [super touchesXXX:withEvent:] in these 4 methods, I thought this should stop the UIPageViewController from receiving touch events, but somehow it seemed that the UIPageViewController recognized a swipe, and cancelled MyUIView touches.

And I noticed another detail, if I touch MyUIView and move from left to right very slowly and to a very little distance, I still got -touchesMoved:withEvent: called. But after a certain distance (maybe 10 points), UIPageViewController seemed recognize a swipe and scroll, and cancelled touches in MyUIView at the same time.

The question is, what happened? How to consume touch events in MyUIView, and stop forwarding the event upstream?

Answer (score 0):

After using the Xcode "debug view hierarchy" feature, I find the view hierarchy of UIPageViewController.view:

[image]

_UIQueuingScrollView looks suspicious, so I logged its gesture recognizers:

```
2016-10-26 19:02:16.846 LSYReader[5202:293575] _UIQueuingScrollView gesture:<UIScrollViewDelayedTouchesBeganGestureRecognizer: 0x6080001b4f20; state = Possible; delaysTouchesBegan = YES; view = <_UIQueuingScrollView 0x7f884003ba00>; target= <(action=delayed:, target=<_UIQueuingScrollView 0x7f884003ba00>)>>
2016-10-26 19:02:16.848 LSYReader[5202:293575] _UIQueuingScrollView gesture:<UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer: 0x7f883e70a240; state = Possible; delaysTouchesEnded = NO; view = <_UIQueuingScrollView 0x7f884003ba00>; target= <(action=handlePan:, target=<_UIQueuingScrollView 0x7f884003ba00>)>; must-fail = {
    <UIScrollViewPagingSwipeGestureRecognizer: 0x6080001dc5c0; state = Possible; view = <_UIQueuingScrollView 0x7f884003ba00>; target= <(action=_handleSwipe:, target=<_UIQueuingScrollView 0x7f884003ba00>)>>
}>
2016-10-26 19:02:16.849 LSYReader[5202:293575] _UIQueuingScrollView gesture:<UIScrollViewPagingSwipeGestureRecognizer: 0x6080001dc5c0; state = Possible; view = <_UIQueuingScrollView 0x7f884003ba00>; target= <(action=_handleSwipe:, target=<_UIQueuingScrollView 0x7f884003ba00>)>; must-fail-for = {
    <UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer: 0x7f883e70a240; state = Possible; enabled = NO; delaysTouchesEnded = NO; view = <_UIQueuingScrollView 0x7f884003ba00>; target= <(action=handlePan:, target=<_UIQueuingScrollView 0x7f884003ba00>)>>
}>
```

And then, I disabled these gesture recognizers, everything works fine in MyUIView now.

```
[_pageViewController.view.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(__kindof UIView * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

    if ([obj isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"_UIQueuingScrollView")]) {
        [obj.gestureRecognizers enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(__kindof UIGestureRecognizer * _Nonnull obj1, NSUInteger idx1, BOOL * _Nonnull stop1) {
            if ([obj1 isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UIScrollViewDelayedTouchesBeganGestureRecognizer")]) {
                obj1.enabled = NO;
            } else if ([obj1 isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer")]) {
                obj1.enabled = NO;
            } else if ([obj1 isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UIScrollViewPagingSwipeGestureRecognizer")]) {
                obj1.enabled = NO;
            }
        }];
    }
}];
```